# Firing an Intent, but I can't seem to find out how to get the package name

Tags: android, android-intent, package

Here is my current code:

```
public ListAdapter createAdapter() {
    appNames = new String[] { "" };
    appNamesList = new ArrayList<String>();

    final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();      
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    packs = pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
    Collections.sort(packs, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm));

    for (int i = 0; i < packs.size(); i++) {
        appNamesList.add(packs.get(i).loadLabel(pm).toString());
    }

    appNames = maker(appNamesList);     
    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, appNames);        
    return adapter;
}
```

I currently have this code updating a ListView for the user to select an app from the list. Now, on my Listener, I need to get the package name. Is there an easy way to get the package name from the code I already have? Or will I need to create another List of package names?

I feel dumb for asking this next question, but is there a way you can start an intent from just the app name? I already have that and it would be a lot easier.

Thanks.

Comment: what is packs in your code? is it an ApplicationInfo instance?

Comment: No, packs is a List<ResolveInfo> object...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok to achieve what you want you need to make some changes in your code.

Make package name part of your appNamesList like

```
appNameList = ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
```

so when you will get the item in your listener using

```
listView.getAdapter().getItem(i);
```

you will get the package name as a part of this item.

now you can use it as you want.

If you are still confused or have any other doubt, let me know.

Comment: Ah. The Hashmap. D'oh! I guess I should have paid more attention in Data Structures last semester. This is definitely the answer I was looking for. Thanks dude. I'm kinda new to stack overflow, so what do I need to do since you provided answer?

Comment: I am happy that my answer is useful for you. Just click on the check sign which is on left top and below number 0 of my annswer to accept it officially :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to call getPackageName() from the context of an [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)?